# AC analysis of circuit: capacitors in parallel with BJTs

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, ac, bjt, short-circuit

[image]

It's been a while since I've done AC analysis for circuits, but the sources I've looked at say to short DC sources to GND, and to treat capacitors as shorts.

Given the placement of C7, I think Q3 can be omitted entirely from the circuit in AC analysis, and R11 goes to GND. Q4's base also shorts to GND.

I also think(?) R15 and R16 get shorted by C8 and C9 respectively. If that's the case, then Q4's base, collector *and* emitter are all grounded? So is it as if Q4 isn't there at all in the AC equivalent circuit (an open circuit, since VBE = 0)?

I don't know for sure how the circuit works, but given it's a compressor, my guess is that when the signal goes high enough, the LEDs hard-clip the signal. Since they're in the feedback path of Q1, the hard-clipping gets mixed with the input in a way such that the signal is unchanged below VCLIP, and is flattened/averaged downward if above VCLIP.

So is the AC version of this circuit really just two transistors instead of the four pictured?

Here's my attempt at re-drawing the circuit:

[image]

Comment: Kind of a weird circuit for me, anyway. The first stage is an emitter follower, so no voltage gain there. The 2nd stage is a CE stage with voltage gain. This appears to drive the output as well as a very odd Q3, which is biased to ground. It would take a serious kick to haul it enough above ground, and only for a half-cycle at most, to activate it, which would then 'do something odd' at the diode midpoint, normally biased halfway between the rails. (I haven't analyzed the 'odd' part of that.) That midpoint is fed back to the input of the CE stage. Novel, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> the sources I've looked at say... to treat capacitors as shorts.

Yes, but only 'large' capacitors which a have a very low impedance at the analysis frequency.

> So is the AC version of this circuit really just two transistors
> instead of the four pictured?

Effectively yes. AC analysis only works properly in linear circuits, and the amplitude of the signal is assumed to be small enough to have no effect on biasing etc. In your circuit Q3 has no bias so it is turned off and presents practically no load (to small AC signals). Any signal that sneaks through is shorted out by C7-C9 so Q4 is irrelevant.

> my guess is that when the signal goes high enough, the LEDs hard-clip
> the signal

Yes, but AC analysis treats the LEDs as fixed resistors, whose values are needed to perform the analysis. Even when not 'hard-clipping' the LEDs have some current going through them which lowers their AC impedance. As signal strength increases more current flows through the LEDs causing their impedance to reduce. For AC analysis you can either assume the LEDs have a fixed resistance, or bias Q3 to represent the effect of higher signal amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Leds are used as current controlled resistors. When the output level grows transistor Q3 finaaly eats off the base current of Q4. In idle state Q4 shorts off the DC current of the leds.

When output level grows enough the leds start to conduct and their reduced AC resistance reduce the audio signal in point Feedback at the end of R4. It's not hard diode clipper. The drive of led DC is slowed down with RC circuit and their AC resistance affects in a place where signal voltage itself couldn't cause substantial current in leds.